A question on strict convexity vs strong convexity
Is it possible to build a function $f: [0, +\infty)$ such that $f, f', f'' > 0$ and $x \mapsto x/ f(x)$ is strictly increasing?
Of course, if $f, f'>0$ and $f''> \epsilon > 0$, this is not possible since $f$ is bounded from below by a parabola and therefore $x/f(x) \to_{x \to +\infty} 0$, but what happens when $\inf f'' = 0$?

Have you looked at something like $f(x)=x+e^{-x}/1000$?

Let's consider $f(x)=x+e^{-x}/5.$ Then we get $f(x)>0$ für $x\geq 0$ and
$$f'(x)=1-e^{-x}/5\geq 1-1/5>0$$
and $$f''(x)=e^{-x}/5>0$$ for $x\geq 0$.
On the other hand
$$\frac{x}{f(x)}=\frac{x}{x+e^{-x}/5}=1-\frac{e^{-x}/5}{x+e^{-x}/5}=1-\frac{1}{1+5xe^{x}}$$
is strictly increasing.
